# How to make Camera on-off sound on programatically

Tags: android, camera

I make a camera and now I want it have function on/off sound when capture or record

I can make it fixed mute or unmute but if I want have button to switch, It not work

With sound:
Add this code to ShutterCallback:

```
   AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   mgr.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

With no sound: Add this code before capture:

```
  AudioManager  mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

And this code to Picture callback:

```
mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```

Comment: make sure that you have provided modify audio setting permission in android manifest file

Comment: yes, problem is combile two state, with each state my app work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for this case:

- Mute sound: pass shuttercallback is null
- Unmute sound: init shuter callback as above

  ```
             Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = null;
              if (hasSound) {
                  shutterCallback = () -> {
                      AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                      mgr.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                  };
              }
              mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, mPicture);
  ```